# AspIdentity - Get Users in Role - Get Roles By User

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity

I have spent all morning on this issue, I'm assuming I'm missing something very obvious.  Using AspIdentity (.net 6), I wish to simply List all Roles for a given USERID and the opposite, All Users in a given RoleId.

In every attempt I have nothing but errors, such as below

> System.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Action' instances are not supported. Path: $.MoveNextAction.
> ---> System.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Action' instances are not supported.

My Code for Users and Roles works jist fine everywhere else, just not to on these two queries.

```
    public async Task<IList<string>> ListRolesByUserId(string filter, string UserId)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(UserId);
        var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

        return roles.ToList();
    }
```

If I put a breakpoint on Var Roles...you can see both the User and the Roles

[image: Auto]

But if I let the resulting IList<> try to Return, I get this

[image: Swagger Error]

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT

Updated Code and Auto

[image]

Comment: What is the type here `var roles`? and why `IList`? Do `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: Roles is resolved as an IList<string> - which is why I declared my Return this way

Comment: `IList` is needed only if you have things like `Add, Remove`. Try `Task<IEnumerable<string>>` and `return roles;`

Comment: Updated - Same result

Comment: This exception is about json serialization. it fails. are you sure that you have list od stings there? What is actual type there? -- `roles.GetType().ToString()`

Comment: This is why I don't allow developers write code like this `var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);` Because you can't tell the type of `roles` There must be a concrete type either on the right or the left of `=`

Comment: I have updated the OP - I am using Swagger to visualize for now and the snapshot is from VS 2022.

Comment: you have not answer my question. Look `IEnumerable<string> es = new List<string>(){"11", "22"};`  I need `Console.WriteLine(es.GetType().ToString());` which in this case would be `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]`. In other words, IEnumerable is not the real type. I want to see the **actual** type

Comment: If i do a simple -  var users = await _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Administrator"); with  Console.WriteLine(users.GetType().ToString()); I get the same System.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Action' instances are not supported.  error

Comment: Do, `pick definition` in `GetUsersInRoleAsync` and post it here. I mean, the method declaration

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know what you mean by the above.